# Can't install scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, scipy, apple-m1

I am currently trying to install scikit-learn module to my Apple M1 macbook. Whatever I do, whichever way I follow returns me an error. First, It got stuck on

```
Installing build dependencies ...
```

Then after I followed a similar post in stackoverflow, the error message I got changed.

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.2.0.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 2
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools<60.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.9.3.tar.gz (42.1 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      ERROR: Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
          status = run_func(*args)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
          return func(self, options, args)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 400, in run
          requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
          result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
          state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
          self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
          if not criterion.candidates:
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
          return bool(self._sequence)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
          return any(self)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
          return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
          candidate = func()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
          self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
          super().__init__(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
          self.dist = self._prepare()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
          dist = self._prepare_distribution()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
          return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
          return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 577, in _prepare_linked_requirement
          dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 69, in _get_prepared_distribution
          abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 48, in prepare_distribution_metadata
          self._install_build_reqs(finder)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 118, in _install_build_reqs
          build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 95, in _get_build_requires_wheel
          return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 685, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 173, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 319, in _call_hook
          raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
      pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesonpy'
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 2
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried to do anything I saw on internet about this problem but nothing worked, what should I do?

Comment: This is actually an error when trying to install `scipy`, and has been an open issue in the scipy repository since at least 2022-09-06 (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16974). Based on the discussion there (and here), it's a problem with the version of Python installed with homebrew. If I were you, my next attempt would be to try a Python environment through [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).